# Pagination and controller methods arguments

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-routing

Here is the problem. I'm using the pagination library of Code Igniter for paginate the results that the model return. The thing is that I've also need to pass some arguments to my controller method so the url is something like this:

> localhost/index.php/controller/paginationNum

And I need to be something like this

> localhost/index.php/controller/paginationNum/arg1/arg2/arg3

How can I ignore the paginationNumber in the Url so I can user the arguments in my controller?

Comment: Do you even know what **"continuous integration"** is ?! Why the hell you would be tagging codeigniter question with it?

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure since I am using pagination combined with Ajax a lot in Codeigniter but can't you just go with:

```
 $this->uri->segment(n);
```

So you filter out the unwanted parts of the URI?

Comment: You mean for the arguments?

Comment: Yes, exactly. You could also go with $this->uri->segment_array() and loop through the array or whatever.

Comment: The problem is that the arguments are optional. If I say something like getRecords(segment(3)) and the segment(3) isn't set it would return error, right?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Yes it would simply return false if the segment doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

**URI class** can help u solving ur problem

use uri segment like this.

```
$this->uri->segment(n)
```

Find more helep from [uri class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/uri.html)

Enjoy Coding :)